# Symmetric Gaussian Lowpass filter - java implementation

Tags: java, filtering, gaussian

**What are the steps in implementing a *5x5 symmetric Gaussian lowpass filter* in image processing?** If I have an image and I want to perform this filter, **what are the basic steps involved here?**

Comment: First make some effort. If it is not enough, then second step: ask a question on stackoverflow

Comment: All of the tutorials are confusing and doesn't seem to have a step by step implementation. They are just explaining what gaussian is, etc. I am just hoping that there is someone kind here that could help.